# Sort chemical elements such as H, He, Li, Be by atomic number in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

I have a long table with columns for sample, analysis number, test method, etc. and, importantly, the chemical element that was analyzed.
I would like to sort my table by sample first, then by chemical element. Element symbols should be in order of increasing atomic number: H < He < Li < Be < B < C < N etc. all the way to Pb.
Can this be done in Excel?

Comment: Create a helper column that will contain the atomic numbers.  Use the helper column to sort by atomic number.

Comment: Thanks @ReddyLutonadio - your approach sounds reasonable, if a little cumbersome. Next question, then: how do I efficiently assign atomic numbers to elements? I'm hoping for an ATOMICNUMBER() function...

Comment: Why would excel have a function for that? Excel is about handling data of all types and it's your job to have the right data, including knowing the atomic numbers.

Comment: Chemistry Stack Exchange [Where can I find a downloadable spreadsheet of element properties?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2793/where-can-i-find-a-downloadable-spreadsheet-of-element-properties)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### (1) Create custom Excel VBA function ATOMICNUMBER()

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> to open the Visual Basic Editor (on the Mac, press <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>), and then click Insert > Module.

Copy and paste the following code to the new module.

```
Function ATOMICNUMBER(arg1 as String) as Integer
    elementSymbols = Array("foo", "H", "He", "Li", "Be", "B", "C", "N", "O", "F", "Ne", "Na", "Mg", "Al", "Si", "P", "S", "Cl", "Ar", "K", "Ca", "Sc", "Ti", "V", "Cr", "Mn", "Fe", "Co", "Ni", "Cu", "Zn", "Ga", "Ge", "As", "Se", "Br", "Kr", "Rb", "Sr", "Y", "Zr", "Nb", "Mo", "Tc", "Ru", "Rh", "Pd", "Ag", "Cd", "In", "Sn", "Sb", "Te", "I", "Xe", "Cs", "Ba", "La", "Ce", "Pr", "Nd", "Pm", "Sm", "Eu", "Gd", "Tb", "Dy", "Ho", "Er", "Tm", "Yb", "Lu", "Hf", "Ta", "W", "Re", "Os", "Ir", "Pt", "Au", "Hg", "Tl", "Pb", "Bi", "Po", "At", "Rn", "Fr", "Ra", "Ac", "Th", "Pa", "U", "Np", "Pu", "Am", "Cm", "Bk", "Cf", "Es", "Fm", "Md", "No", "Lr", "Rf", "Db", "Sg", "Bh", "Hs", "Mt", "Ds", "Rg", "Cn", "Nh", "Fl", "Mc", "Lv", "Ts", "Og")
    ATOMICNUMBER = 0
    For i = 1 To UBound(elementSymbols)
        If elementSymbols(i) = arg1 Then
            ATOMICNUMBER = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Close the Visual Basic Editor.

### (2) Add helper column

Insert a new column next to the element symbols.

Fill it with `=ATOMICNUMBER(`*adjacent cell containing element symbol*`)`.

### (3) Sort

Select all the data.

Menu Data > Sort...

Sort by sample first, then by atomic number.

Answer (score 6):

Sort the data by the atomic number. Here's a query to return some data from Wikipedia:

```
let
    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_elements_by_atomic_properties")),
    Data0 = Source{0}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data0,{{"Z", type text}, {"Name", type text}, {"Symbol", type text}, {"Average atomic mass", type text}, {"Electronegativity (Pauling)", type text}, {"First Ionization Energy (eV)", type text}, {"Radii (pm) Atomic", type text}, {"Radii (pm) Van der Waals", type text}, {"Radii (pm) Covalent", type text}, {"Valence electrons", type text}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([Z] <> "Z")),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Filtered Rows",{{"Z", Int64.Type}, {"Valence electrons", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type1","—","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Radii (pm) Van der Waals"}),
    #"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value","—","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Radii (pm) Covalent"}),
    #"Replaced Value2" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value1","—","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Radii (pm) Atomic"}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Replaced Value2",{{"Radii (pm) Atomic", Int64.Type}, {"Radii (pm) Covalent", Int64.Type}, {"First Ionization Energy (eV)", type number}}),
    #"Replaced Value3" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type2","—","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Electronegativity (Pauling)"}),
    #"Changed Type3" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Replaced Value3",{{"Electronegativity (Pauling)", type number}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type3",{{"Z", "Atomic Number"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

You can use Data>Get Data>From Other Sources>Blank Query, then when the Power Query Editor opens, you can open Advanced Editor, then paste the query above into the Advanced Editor window. When you click "Close & Load" it will put the data back into a new sheet in your workbook. You can then either:

1. Use `XLOOKUP` to add the atomic number to your data, then sort by that column, or if you want to get a little more complicated but more powerful,
2. Load both datasets to the PowerPivot Data Model, create a join on element name, then set the Sort properties for the element column to use the Atomic number. If you do that, the elements will be sorted by atomic number in all pivot tables created from the Power Pivot Data Model

Just as an aside, if you load that query into Power Query, you can also select the "Name" column, then use the Transform>Create Data Type option, like this:

[image]

Which allows you to do interesting things like this:

[image]

Comment: That's fantastic! But maybe a tad over-engineered for my situation. I didn't know about XLOOKUP -- sounds pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.
For example if you have this .

[image]

You can click on the column you want to sort and use the Sort and Filter tool from the Home tab in Excel and sort it smallest to largest like below

[image]

Then when this message comes up, make sure it's on Expand the selection and click Sort

[image]